# asp.net mvc3, how to implement the sidebar section correctly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I build my web site using asp.net mvc3, layout is 2 columns, main content with sidebar.

I create a section for sidebar.  this sidebar will show top 10 articles. what I did right now is to query the top 10 articles on every controller.

is there a way to do it in one place and using it on all controllers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using `Html.RenderAction([methodname], [controllername])`.  So in your _Layout.cshtml, you might end up with something like:

```
<div id="content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>

@{ Html.RenderAction("ShowTopArticles", "Article"); }
```

Then in your `ArticleController`:

```
private readonly int MaxArticles = 10;

[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult ShowTopArticles()
{
    var model = articleRepository.GetTopArticles(MaxArticles);

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Marking the action with the attribute `ChildActionOnly` means it can only be invoked by a call to `Html.Action()` or `Html.RenderAction()`.